# Delete query referencing all values not in a duplicate query

Tags: sql

I am attempting to create a delete query that removes duplicates.

I attempted to create a duplicate query. I then created a delete query in hopes to delete all records additional to the "First" record from my duplicate query.

-- Code for Duplicate query

```
SELECT First(tblExpressLaneOTARCHIVE.[Date Worked]) AS [Date Worked Field], First(tblExpressLaneOTARCHIVE.[ID Number]) AS [ID Number Field], First(tblExpressLaneOTARCHIVE.[Start Time]) AS [Start Time Field], Count(tblExpressLaneOTARCHIVE.[Date Worked]) AS NumberOfDups, First(tblExpressLaneOTARCHIVE.ID) AS ID
FROM tblExpressLaneOTARCHIVE
GROUP BY tblExpressLaneOTARCHIVE.[Date Worked], tblExpressLaneOTARCHIVE.[ID Number], tblExpressLaneOTARCHIVE.[Start Time]
HAVING (((Count(tblExpressLaneOTARCHIVE.[Date Worked]))>1) AND ((Count(tblExpressLaneOTARCHIVE.[Start Time]))>1));
```

--Code for Delete Query

```
DELETE tblExpressLaneOTArchive.ID
FROM tblExpressLaneOTArchive
WHERE (((tblExpressLaneOTArchive.ID)<>([qryExpressLaneDuplicates].[ID])));
```

When I run the delete query I receive an input box asking for the value of qryExpressLaneDuplicates.ID

Comment: IS this MS Access?

Comment: @Odwalla . . . Tag your question with the database you are using.  Also sample data would be very helpful, so it is clear what *you* mean by "duplicate".

Comment: Can you please provide the flavor of sql that you are using? This sounds like you are using some sort of GUI system and not providing whatever kind of link to the data from the SELECT query to the DELETE query. In Sql Server you could either combine the two into 1 DELETE query or you could put the results of the select into a temp table or table variable and then use that in the DELETE query.

Comment: My apologies, this is MS Access.